# Please welcome anonymous2 back to the moderation team!

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm pleased to announce that [anonymous2](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/49/anonymous2) has decided to return to the moderation team! He'll be joining us from today, back handling flags and keeping the site clean.

[image: anonymous2]

I'm sure anonymous2's record speaks for itself, and it gives me great pleasure to welcome him back to the moderation team.

So, please wish anonymous2 well with this (not so) new role!

Comment: Welcome back! Glad to have you on board again.

Comment: Welcome back :-)

Comment: Thank you all!  I can honestly say that my time away from here felt like a part of me was missing.  I'm thrilled to be back, and I'm excited to see the steps that have been taken to recover from the fallout from last year's events.